# NSAttributedString change color and font size

Tags: html, swift, string, nsattributedstring

Hi guys I have small problem, I'm using func:

```
static func convertFromHTMLString(_ input: String?) -> NSAttributedString? {

        guard let input = input else { return nil }

        guard let data = input.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true) else { return nil  }
        return try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
    }
```

to read my Strings from Localizable.strings with attributes like this:

[image: String]

But when I run my app it looks that:

[image: App screen]

This change my Label color to black and font size to something like 10-12 ;/ 
My Label should have white color and font size 17, anyone know how to fix it? 
Thanks ! :)

@Edit1 
The solution must look like this
[image: Android version]
This is how it looks on Android.

Answer (score 0):

```
func convertFromHTMLString(_ input: String?) -> NSAttributedString? {

    guard let input = input else { return nil }

    guard let data = input.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true) else { return nil  }


    if let string = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil).string
    {
        //Set color and font
        let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white , NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 17.0)!  ]
        let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: myAttribute)
        return myAttrString
    }


    return nil
}
```

Comment: It change color and font size, but now don't working <b> and <big> and this is most important for me ;/

Comment: Send me example html like text

Comment: You already asked about <b> and <big> earlier and that was marked a duplicate. Did you try the answer in the linked question?

Comment: @Szczowio i try this  
var html = "\n    <b><big> Nowy wspabiay swiat </big></b><br>\n  <b> Aldous Huxley</b><br><br>\n  Exampleeee " wrok correctly

Comment: @koen That's true. I realized answer from my lasy question who you linked me but now I have this problem, I have tried to find solution in internet, forums, Facebook and nothing ;o This is horrible important for me to find the solution. 
#Stefan I can't put it to var, because I have something like 500 strings, that's why I must have it in Localizable.strings, when I tried have it on var It still work the same and cut my String I don't know why ;/
#Edit1 I added how it should look in solution from my Android project, on iOS I must look the same.

Comment: Instead of <big> and <b>, maybe look into `UIFont.TextStyle` to set the font for your title (Nowy wspabiay swiat), subtitle (Aldous Huxley), body (exampleeee). Maybe you don't need to use HTML at all?  See also here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/textstyle

Comment: You can also wrap your html like a full html page with <html><head><style>insert styles here</style></head><body>insert html here</body></html> and specify the font and other traits in the css. Do this before generating the attributed string. This works well for me.